# Why I cannot ask further questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

My profile can be be found in

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53124/ze1

I cannot ask further questions. It seems that this option is blocked or damaged in my PC. How I can resolve this problem?.

Comment: It would be slightly helpful if you told us what sort of error you receive when trying to ask a question.

Comment: I've only counted 36 questions in the last 30 days, so unless you've deleted some of your questions, it should not be problem with [question quotas](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770).

Comment: Another common problem when asking questions is the [quality filter](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/message-about-quality-standards). But this is all just guesswork until you give us more details. (Screenshot would be nice, too.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I can write the title and the main text of the question but it seems that the icon of *Tag* is disactived also when clicking on **post your question** nothing happen and the page remain unchanged and does not go further.

Comment: Unrelated: why did you see fit to delete more than 25% of the questions you asked?

Comment: @Did: because I have been solved them.

Comment: Then you might want to reconsider the timescale of the process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Including your deleted questions, you have asked $50$ questions in the last $30$ days. That is the limit.

It used to be the case that a message was presented when you tried posting the $51^{\text{st}}$ question, but there was a request to prevent asking the $51^{\text{st}}$ question so that people wouldn't spend time writing the question only to be told they can't post it. I am surprised that the option is not available, and that a message is not displayed when attempting to ask a question.

**Possible Feature Request:** Enable the "Ask Question" link and display a notice informing that the user has asked $50$ questions in the last $30$ days, and tell them when they can ask another question.

Comment: In what you wrote about getting the message before typing the question, you probably meant [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89670/please-warn-about-exceeding-50-question-limit-prior-to-asking-a-new-question) from meta.SO.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thanks for finding that. I was in a rush last night and did not look for it.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: No, I never receive a message like that.

Comment: @ZE1: Sure. The point is that the post Martin cited talks about a change in the process that I had mentioned in my answer. The message is no longer shown.

Comment: @robjohn: So, I must waiting until the end of this month to post some questions.

Comment: @ZE1: The question quota is for last 30 days, not for calendar month; see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/question-limit-per-month). I see that you have [asked a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345539/rank-of-a-direct-sum-of-groups) on 29-03-2013; so on 29-04-2013 you should be able to ask a new question. (I do not know when you asked the questions you have deleted.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Ok thank you very much for clarification.